# Creating Custom Control - DataSource is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

I'm trying to create a custom control based on UIScrollView.
The control should get the information necessary through its dataSource object (same behaviour as UITableView or UIPickerView).
The problem is that I'm trying to define the dataSource through Interface Builder and not by code. (ex. you can set a UITableView dataSource to File's owner in a .xib file)
Here's my new control header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol HorizontalPickerDataSource;

@interface HorizontalPicker : UIScrollView
@property (nonatomic,assign) IBOutlet id <HorizontalPickerDataSource> dataSource;
@end

@protocol HorizontalPickerDataSource 
- (NSInteger)numberOfColumnsInHorizontalPicker:(HorizontalPicker *)horizontalPicker;
- (UIView *)horizontalPicker:(HorizontalPicker *)horizontalPicker viewForColumn:(NSInteger)column;
@end
```

Pretty straightforward.

The UIViewController that adopts the HorizontalPicker should be its dataSource.
I'm defining it through Interface Builder since I set the dataSource an IBOutlet.
 [image]

I override initWtihCoder and logged the dataSource there (after creating the object of course) and it appears to be nil.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self){
        NSLog(@"dataSource: %@",self.dataSource);
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}
```

the setup method whole logic based on dataSource not being nil.
Why is dataSource nil and how can I fix it?
Thank you for your time (:
Edit #1
Here's my implementation of NSCoding, what's wrong with it?

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    id dataSource = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"dataSource"];
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self){
        self.dataSource = dataSource;
        NSLog(@"dataSource: %@",self.dataSource);
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [super encodeWithCoder:aCoder];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.dataSource forKey:@"dataSource"];
}
```

Comment: Under ARC, make it weak, not assign.

Comment: @quellish Thank you for the note, but this still doesn't fix the issue :/

Comment: That's why it wasn't an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to completely implement [NSCoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for this to work. In your case, your `initWithCoder:` is not decoding the datasource. You need to do something like this:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
     id ds = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"dataSource"];
     if(self = [self initWithDataSource:ds){
         NSLog(@"dataSource: %@",self.dataSource);
         [self setup];
     }
     return self;
 }
```

You should also provide the companion method in NSCoding, `encodeWithCoder:`.

Comment: Hey, I tried to implement NSCoding but I guess I did something wrong since the NSLog still prints nil. I posted the 2 methods in an edit in the original question. What could be causing dataSource to still be nil? Thank you!